# AudioInputStream byte to float conversion

Tags: java, signal-processing

I've got an `AudioInputStream` and have retrieved the bytes from it using a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, however when converting this to a float array the numbers are a lot bigger than expected. This is the code below, the audio sample is 16bits per sample and 2 channels.

```
float[] f = new float[bytes.length / 4];

for (int i = 0, j = 0; i != f.length; ++i, j += 4) {

    short left = (short) ((bytes[i] & 0xff) | (bytes[i + 1] << 8));

    short right = (short) ((bytes[i + 2] & 0xff) | (bytes[i + 3] << 8));

    float avg = left + right;

    avg = avg / 2;

    f[i] = avg;
}
```

And the code to convert into bytes:

```
byte[] data = null;

try {

    final ByteArrayOutputStream baout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[(bytePerFrmame == AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED ? 1 * 1024 : bytePerFrmame * 1024)];
    int c;

    while ((c = din.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
        baout.write(buffer, 0, c);
    }

    baout.close();
    data = baout.toByteArray();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return data;
```

Comment: _the numbers are a lot bigger than expected_... What were you expecting? The data bytes are mapped to values between -32768 and 32767 (and so are `short`s). Divide by 32768.0 for float values within +/- 1.

Comment: @SleuthEye i was getting numbers in the 100/200s, and when applying the FFT to the float array it was not looking correct (in contrast to audacity)

Comment: Perhaps you could show us a sample input, how you compute the FFT (including which FFT library you are using) and the corresponding results and tell us why/how you think it does not look correct.

Comment: Is the input really little-endian?

Comment: It might depend on the endianness of the architecture of the computer where you are processing the samples. Do you know the endianness in which your samples were packed as? I see that your first block of code tries to repack bytes expected in the order [LowByte,HighByte]. It may be that the samples come in the order [HighByte,LowByte] instead?

Comment: I sent the endianess as little,  as I use audioformat,  when reading in audios treat